# Google Maps V3 API key doesn't work

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've gotten my meeting list system working and I've tested here at home and here the maps work fine (the IP address starting with 76).

When I deploy it to my website, I get the API error:

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site.

My website is "oameetings.org". It is an add-on domain to my "kierpro.com" main website right now. It points to the "kierpro.com/phone" folder. My IP address, according to BlueHost is 66.147.242.96.

I have tried every one of the keys shown, and they do not work.  I've also tried almost every other variation of each, including adding "www.", "http://www.", "http://", but nothing works.

Comment: PS:  I'm using it currently WITHOUT the key, but I want it set up in case it comes up against the usage limits.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are creating keys for server apps. Those are for apps directly accessing things like Google's web services. You need to select the "Create new Browser Key..." button to create a new key for your domain. Looks like you're using http://oameetings.org in the link you provided, so use that domain but also create one for kierpro.com/phone for any maps served off that domain.

Comment: Ahhh... I totally missed the browser key thing.
Now it works except when I use the sub-domains.  I have esp.oameetings.org and fr.oameetings.org and they simply help flip a switch giving a different language.
Any idea why it would work in the main domain, but not the subdomains?  I tried "*.oameetings.org/*, but that didn't work either.  (PS:  I removed the key again so that it would work while we were testing the multi-lingual capabilities.)

Comment: @user1460275 Did you ever figure out the problem with the subdomains? I'm having the same issue: the key won't work on any subdomain, even when "referrers" is empty in the api console.