# Can't make Google Maps Engine work on my website

Tags: google-maps, google-app-engine

I am trying to embed the map I made in google map engine in my website. I can't make the simple google map engine's code work. I copy paste the sample code of google map engine and change the details according to my own project but it doesn't work. I see the base map but I don't see any of the layers. I add my own API key and it gave error and even without it, it doesn't work. I am not working on any server for time being, is that anyhow related to the server issues? I would really appreciate it if you anyone would tell me where I am doing wrong.

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Maps Engine Layer</title>

 <style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
 </style>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

    <script>
       function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.467216, -2.233701)
              };

             var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
             mapOptions);

            var mapsEngineLayer = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer({
            layerId: '16665525185230662248-09052745394509652502',
            map: map
              });
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

       </script>
     </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your code gives me a javascript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'MapsEngineLayer' of undefined`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah I receive the same but this code is exactly the same as what google map engine tutorial gives so the only property that I have change is the layer ID and coordinates which I replaced them my project case. that's why I can't understand what is wrong with the map and it's layers as it's already a published map in my Google map engine account and I can see the layers in google map engine account correctly.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-mapsengine

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the [visualization library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/visualization) at a minimum.

From the example you reference:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=visualization&sensor=false"></script>
```

After that I get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mapsengine&passive=1209600…Fmaproot%2Fjson%3Foutput%3Djsonp%26access_token%26callback%3D_xdc_._w3rg1a
```

Perhaps you need to allow access.

Comment: yeah it doesn't work with that as well. in the tutorial it said that in business projects or non-business projects one need to add API key instead of libraries=visualization. I did that and it gives me error as access denied. I saw different answers to similar question about this error here in stackoverflow and the answers were that it should work without API code it is supposed to work. I can't understand what is going wrong here

Comment: Can you provide a link to the SO question/answer that said that?  Have you made your map public?

Comment: Yeah sure!
This is what I see in my google map engine account as property of my map:
Shared with: Map Editors  create new  | modify
Viewable by: Map Viewers  create new  | modify

I read these two and in all comments I noticed that their code works without API Key while mine doesn't work even without code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088791/google-maps-v3-api-key-doesnt-work
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301269/new-google-api-key-google-maps-api-v3-doesnt-work-for-google-places-api

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mapsenginelayers#loading_the_visualization_library) says "Google Maps API for Business developers must use a `client` parameter in place of the `key` parameter", not what you said.  Neither of the questions that you posted links to talks about the MapsEngineLayer, just the API, which doesn't require a key in general, might with MapsEngineLayer.

Comment: Yeah Sorry my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable the [google maps engine API](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/) to allow your app to access the visualization. And add the `&libraries=visualization` to the api uri request.

Go to the Google API console page to enable it for your projects api.

Comment: Oh Thanks! yes I didn't have the API enabled! I will try it to see whether it will work with this or not.

Comment: Thanks for your helps, it finally worked! the problem was that google maps engine API was disabled and my map wasn't public.